# Test not execute successfully( Insert failed. REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [LastName, Company]

Tags: apex

I have the Rest API that will return id if Lead/Contact exits in Salesforce with emailid using get if record not exists then create a new Lead for that record .I write the follwing code

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping='/1.0/Persons/*')

   global class SQUser{

    @HttpGet

   global static Void getLeadContact(){
     String EmailID = RestContext.request.params.get('Email_id');
     LIST<Contact> conID = [Select ID from Contact where Email=:EmailID LIMIT 1];
     LIST<Lead>    ledID = [Select ID from Lead where Email=:EmailID LIMIT 1];
     if(conID.size()>0){
      RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     // Return a single Contact as an example
      RestContext.response.responseBody = 
 Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize((Contact)[Select ID from Contact where Email=:EmailID

 LIMIT 1]));

 }

  else if(ledID.size()>0){

 RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 // Return a single Lead as an example

 RestContext.response.responseBody = 

 Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize((Lead)[Select ID from Lead where Email=:EmailID LIMIT 
   1]));
  }else{

RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 // Return a single Null as an example

 RestContext.response.responseBody = 

 Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize((null)));

   }

  }

 @HttpPost

 global static void CreateRecord(){

//Initlize the lead object

Lead ledID = new Lead();

//Get requested parameter one by one

ledID.FirstName = RestContext.request.params.get('First_nm');

ledID.LastName = RestContext.request.params.get('Last_nm');

ledID.Phone = RestContext.request.params.get('Phone');

ledID.Email = RestContext.request.params.get('Email');

ledID.Company= RestContext.request.params.get('Company');

// insert lead record in salesforce 

insert ledID;

RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 // Return a single Lead as an example

 RestContext.response.responseBody = 

 Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize((Lead)[Select ID from Lead where ID=:ledID.ID]));

 } 
}
```

> But i test HttpPost method using follwing code then got the error message " Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [LastName, Company]: [LastName, Company]"

```
   @isTest

 private class SQUserTest {

 static {

     // setup test data  

    }

static testmethod void TestCreateRecord(){
RestRequest req = new RestRequest();

RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

// pass the req and resp objects to the method   

req.requestURI = 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/1.0/Persons?

 First_nm=Arun&Last_nm=kumar&Phone=97757587&Email=kumar@gmail.com&Company=GL';

req.httpMethod = 'POST';

RestContext.request = req;

RestContext.response = res;

SQUser.CreateRecord();

System.debug('Insert executed successfully.');

 }
}
```

Comment: Have you test to display the parameters in your `CreateRecord()` method ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Persons/*')
global class SQUser{   
    @HttpPost
    global static void CreateRecord(String First_nm,String Last_nm,String Phone,String Email,String Company){        
        //Initlize the lead object        
        Lead ledID = new Lead();

        //Get requested parameter one by one       
        ledID.FirstName = First_nm;
        System.debug('FirstName'+ledID.FirstName);

        ledID.LastName = Last_nm;
        System.debug('LastName'+ledID.LastName);

        ledID.Phone = Phone;

        ledID.Email = Email;

        ledID.Company= Company;
        System.debug('Company'+ledID.Company);

        // insert lead record in salesforce         
        insert ledID;

        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        // Return a single Lead as an example       
        RestContext.response.responseBody =             
            Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize((Lead)[Select ID from Lead where ID=:ledID.ID]));        
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class SQUserTest {   
    static {       
        // setup test data        
    }

    static testmethod void TestCreateRecord(){
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();

        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        // pass the req and resp objects to the method           
        String json ='{"First_nm" : "","Last_nm"  : "arjun","Phone"    : "1234567890","Email"    : "xxxx@gmail.com","Company": "xxx"}';

        req.requestURI = 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/1.0/Persons/
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';

        req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(json);

        RestContext.request = req;

        RestContext.response = res;

        SQUser.CreateRecord('First','Last','Phone','Email','Company');

        System.debug('Insert executed successfully.');        
    }
}
```

Thanks 
Nagarjuna

Comment: nagarjuna -- on SFSE, we try and avoid reminding the original poster to make our solutions as accepted except perhaps in the case where there has been an extended comment trail back-and-forth